# Custom UIimagePicker for input type file in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an HTML file displayed in a `UIWebView` which contains file input field. When I click on file input the standard `UIImagePickerController` opens and show me the two options **"Take Photo or Video"** and **"Photo Library"**. I wanna have a custom version of the picker when I click on the file input. I wanna show/select only videos and no photos and I wanna show only the option **"Photo Library"**, it is possible?

Comment: If you only want the photo library then, You should only add the photo library option in alert controller

Comment: at the moment i have no control in alert controller, it appears automatically. How i can interact with this default behaviour?